# cygwin: can't execute PHP script via PATH

Tags: php, windows, cygwin

I have written a PHP script "toalpha" (purpose not relevant to this question). The script is in $HOME/bin.  If my CWD is $HOME/bin, I can execute it by typing "./toalpha".  But if I simply type "toalpha", I get a message:
   Could not open input file: /c/barry/bin/toalpha

Some information that may be relevant:

. I recently upgraded my desktop from WinXP to Win7.

. This is the first time that I have made my own userid be an ordinary user instead of an admin.  (I tried to do that on XP, but ran into problems and went back to having my normal userid be the admin.  Don't need a solution for that because I'm no longer running XP and besides it was my own fault.)

. My $HOME is /c/barry
I did that by adding the following to the .bashrc created when I installed cygwin:
  mount C: /c
  HOME=/c/barry
  cd
  . .bashrc

. The first two lines of the PHP script are:

```
#!/c/xampp/php/php
<?php
```

. Yes, the copy of PHP I want to use is in C:\xampp\php\php.exe

. I have another, similar script that I wrote on WinXP.  It starts with the same two lines.  It worked fine under XP, but doesn't work on Win7.

My best guesses at the source of the problem:

1. A difference between XP and Win7
2. I fumbled the home directory change in some way.  IIRC, when I installed cygwin on XP I did some trickery so it would start directly in C:\barry but I couldn't remember how I did that when I installed it on Win7, so I took the "easy way out".

Answer (score -1):

bash is passing to "C:\xampp\php\php.exe"
the file name "/c/barry/bin/toalpha"
but that is a cygwin path and your PHP does not regognize it.

You should convert it in an understandable one using
cygpath

Try
/c/xampp/php/php $(cygpath -w /c/barry/bin/toalpha )

Comment: I had to actually stick the path name in there, that is, C:\barry\bin\toalpha
 instead of $(cygpath -w /c/barry/bin/toalpha).  The code that handles #! scripts expects to see a literal path there, not a construct that needs to be evaluated by the shell.

But thank you, by applying your suggestion (as modified) I now have a script that I can execute anywhere.